# Reading data from bluetooth device in android

Tags: java, android, bluetooth

I am using bluetooth chat in order to connect and recieve data from a bluetooth device.

I use the following code for reading data:

```
public void run() {
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int bytes;
    Log.v("MR", "start listening....");

    // Keep listening to the InputStream while connected
    while (true) {
        try {
            // Read from the InputStream
            Log.d("MR", "buffer in try");

            bytes = mmInStream.read(buffer);
            Log.d("MR", "input stream :"+(new String(buffer)));
            // Send the obtained bytes to the UI Activity
            mHandler.obtainMessage(Conn.MESSAGE_READ, bytes, -1, buffer).sendToTarget();
            Log.d("MR", "buffer after");

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("MR", "Error :"+e.getMessage());
            //
            connectionLost();
           // break;
        }

        Log.d("MR", "buffer after while");
    }
}
```

The device is sending data all the time without stopping.

With the above code I get the message of:

```
Log.d("MR", "buffer in try");
```

then it goes to the next line:

```
bytes=mmInStream.read(buffer);
```

and never returns from that call. I guess this is because it starts reading data from the device and doesn't stop until it disconnects. How can I read a certain amount of bytes at a time?

**EDIT**

Unless it stay to the `bytes = mmInStream.read(buffer);` code due to that it don;t get any data back on from the device?

Comment: th problem might not be the certain that i havce write on the top.  i think it must be the port that it's make the communication.  is it possible for the two devices to be connected but on the socket nothing to be transmitted os there is something that going wrong with the communication?

Comment: Upvotes would be nice lol...hope you are having some success

Comment: having exactly same problem

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I use DataInputStreams instead as you can do a readFully() method which waits to read a certain number of bytes before returning.  I setup the BT connection like this:

```
BluetoothDevice btDevice = bta.getRemoteDevice(macAddress);
BluetoothSocket btSocket = InsecureBluetooth.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(
                    btDevice, UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB"), false);

btSocket.connect();
InputStream input = btSocket.getInputStream();
DataInputStream dinput = new DataInputStream(input);
```

then later on when I want to read I use readFully:

```
dinput.readFully(byteArray, 0, byteArray.length);
```

Comment: the InsecureBluetooth. is a class that you have create or is something that i have to import or a contasnt because i can't find anything?

Comment: You can get InsecureBluetooth.java from here...http://code.google.com/p/payforwarding/source/browse/trunk/source/Android/monac/src/jp/android_group/payforward/monac/bts/InsecureBluetooth.java?r=103

Comment: i have try it and i connect on the device. i also use bond state to check if is connect and i get return code 12, which mean that is ok, but i still do not get any data back from the device to my android device.   it might be any problem with the socket?

Comment: is connected and i notice that when i disable the bluetooth device and send data to the device on my android device i get IOException. if am not doing wrong this means that the socket is close and can not send or receive data?   if am correct on this why it does not receive any data before i close the bluetooth device?

Comment: Step through the debugger and and see where the code stops, you might also be throwing an error without knowing so wrap everything in a try catch and go from there.  if it stops at readFully or the read and never comes out then you are correct in that the device is not sending any data.

Comment: hmnm that would mean your device is not sending...can you show the setup code to your Bluetooth?  Are you using what I have above?

Comment: the same code i use it with the hyper terminal on my pc and i can send and receive data between my android phone and pc with no problem.   could it be something with the socket communication with the certain device that can connect but can not send any data between the android phone and my ECG device? my android device Bluetooth version is 2.1 and ECG device is 2.0. it may be communication problem of the versions of bluetooth?

Comment: Lol that is what I am doing right now with phone, creating an ECG Phone app with our ECG device.  What Phone are you using?  I had problems with SPP and some android phones not working with our device.  Also if you want send me your email and we can take this offline some more.

Comment: am using the htc desire with android 2.3.3(just update) with bluetooth 2.1 and the ECG device is the dyna-vision outdoor  with bluetooth 2.0.   my email is pr.prokopiou@gmail.com.  i will appreciated if you can help me some or if i know something i can provide it to you.

Comment: @prokopis,@JPM: I am facing the same problem in connecting my bluetooth tire sensor with my android phone. It gets stuck when I am trying to read InputStream. Can you please assist me for this? I would be greatly appreciate your help. Mine email id is : yunusluniwala@gmail.com