# Read data from paired Bluetooth devices in Android

Tags: android, bluetooth

I am working on an android 4.0 application which reads data from the paired bluetooth device. I am able to search discoverable bluetooth device and pair the devices. However, I am unsure of how to read data from Bluetooth device via serial port? Does android system support SERIAL PORT? Because I cannot find the serial port like COM1 or COM2 in the android system. At the moment, I am using the BluetoothSocket to pair the device. However, is there any way to read data from Bluetooth serial port like Windows does?

```
socket = _devices.get(k).createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(MY_UUID_SECURE);
socket.connect();
```

Any helps appreciated! Thanks in adance.

Regards,

Charles

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reading data from bluetooth device in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8409180/reading-data-from-bluetooth-device-in-android)

Answer (score 10):

Yes there is.  The `socket` you receive can give you an `InputStream` instance.  If the `socket` is connected, you can then read data (`char`, `String` or `byte`, depending on what reader you will wrap around your `InputStream`, if you wrap one).

To open a **serial port** with the device, you have to use the Serial Port Profile in the UUID you use to create your socket.  A simple UUID thrown around on the web is

```
00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB
```

You can then create your socket, connect to it, get streams and read/write bytes with them.  Example :

```
private static final String UUID_SERIAL_PORT_PROFILE 
                       = "00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB";

private BluetoothSocket mSocket = null;
private BufferedReader mBufferedReader = null;

private void openDeviceConnection(BluetoothDevice aDevice)
        throws IOException {
    InputStream aStream = null;
    InputStreamReader aReader = null;
    try {
        mSocket = aDevice
                .createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord( getSerialPortUUID() );
        mSocket.connect();
        aStream = mSocket.getInputStream();
        aReader = new InputStreamReader( aStream );
        mBufferedReader = new BufferedReader( aReader );
    } catch ( IOException e ) {
        Log.e( TAG, "Could not connect to device", e );
        close( mBufferedReader );
        close( aReader );
        close( aStream );
        close( mSocket );
        throw e;
    }
}

private void close(Closeable aConnectedObject) {
    if ( aConnectedObject == null ) return;
    try {
        aConnectedObject.close();
    } catch ( IOException e ) {
    }
    aConnectedObject = null;
}

private UUID getSerialPortUUID() {
    return UUID.fromString( UUID_SERIAL_PORT_PROFILE );
}
```

And then, somewhere in your code you can read from the reader:

```
String aString = mBufferedReader.readLine();
```

And you can do the same thing in opposite direction using `OutputStream` and various writers.

Comment: But your code is not working. Its saying could not connect to device

Comment: @AMIamitekh that's a 5 years old question and you expect the code to just work as posted?