# stringAsBytes unknown Function in Android

Tags: java, android, bluetooth

I am working on a bluetooth data transfer between two devices and during my research I found this piece of code and I didn't understand very well this stringAsBytes functinality (I guess it's to convert a bytes array to String) and I didn't know how to solve it because it appears as an error.

[image]

Comment: What are you trying to do with that method. I am hearing this method in java first time.

Comment: I found this code and I want to understand it but I couldn't understand that stringAsBytes thing

Comment: can you please post link where you found that.

Comment: i think you have take this piece of code from internet and that person may created one method which named as stringAsBytes, or it may be possible that there is third party library used. Better you take data from inputstream and read data using bufferedreader.

Comment: check this url for reading from bluetooth, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10996803/read-data-from-paired-bluetooth-devices-in-android

Comment: this is the link @ShreeKrishna http://manojprasaddevelopers.blogspot.com/2012/02/bluetooth-data-transfer-example.html

Comment: @SilvansSolanki I was thinking the same way but I wanted to make sure if this method really exists. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

'stringAsBytes' is not a method in that code. It is an Array/Hashmap in which the red color line is assigning a value '0' to its 'byteString.length-1' element.

You have to declare the 'stringAsBytes' as an ArrayList/Hashmap before using it.

*PS : Method has a '(' and Collection has a '['*

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be an array that was a member or static member of the original enclosing class (from where you have copied this code). It may have been used for some other logic in the class, but it is irrelevant in this piece of code in your case. Just delete it.