# How to read strings from a bluetooth socket in java

Tags: java, android, io, bluetooth

I am trying to read strings from a Bluetooth SPP server into my Android client. The server works fine, and sends the strings to the client as is evidenced in the Logcat.The LogCat indicates that bytes are read in from the btSocket. However, my attempt to read from the socket and display to the strings to the TextView has been futile. [Here](http://paste.ubuntu.com/1490814/) is the Android client and here is the [logcat](http://paste.ubuntu.com/1490815/) to evidence that the server works fine. Some Android & java guru to kindly assist. Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reading data from bluetooth device in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8409180/reading-data-from-bluetooth-device-in-android)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try something like this :

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
int bytes;
inFromServer = nmeaServerSocket.getInputStream();

bytes = inFromServer.read(buffer);
String readMessage = new String(buffer, 0, bytes);
Log.d(TAG, "Message :: "+readMessage);
```

Hope it helps you.

Thanks.

Comment: Thanks Sharma,That really helped. Someone also suggested that I should have the bluetooth code as a service rather than an Activity, whats your take on that?

Comment: @nmvictor yes that can be good way. You can use service to communicate and you can have handlers within the service which will receive data from server and send data to your client activity.

Comment: I see that above code works for up to 1024 bytes. How do you know when the bytes have all been received?