# Unable to read bytes from Bluetooth stream, without a logging the number of bytes read

Tags: android, bluetooth

```
    private class ConnectedThread extends Thread {
        private /*final*/ BluetoothSocket mmSocket;
        private /*final*/ InputStream mmInStream;
        private /*final*/ OutputStream mmOutStream;

        public ConnectedThread(BluetoothSocket socket) {
            mmSocket = socket;
            InputStream tmpIn = null;
            OutputStream tmpOut = null;

            // Get the input and output streams, using temp objects because
            // member streams are final
            try {
                tmpIn = socket.getInputStream();
                tmpOut = socket.getOutputStream();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Error connecting IO streams.");
            }

            mmInStream = tmpIn;
            mmOutStream = tmpOut;
        }

        public void run() {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];  // buffer store for the stream
            int bytes; // bytes returned from read()

            // Keep listening to the InputStream until an exception occurs
            while (true) {
                try {
                    if ((bytes = mmInStream.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                        //Send the obtained bytes to the UI activity
                        //mHandler.obtainMessage(MESSAGE_READ, bytes, -1, buffer).sendToTarget();
                        Log.i(TAG, "Read (" + bytes + ") bytes.");
                        String readBytesStr = new String(buffer, 0, bytes, "ASCII");
                        Log.i(TAG, "Bytes from stream (" + bytes + "): " + readBytesStr);
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "Exception occurred: stopped listening to stream.");
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        /* Call this from the main activity to send data to the remote device */
        public void write(byte[] bytes) {
            try {
                mmOutStream.write(bytes);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "ConnectedThread(): Exception in write()");
            }

            String temp = new String(bytes);
            Log.i(TAG, "Wrote: " + temp);
        }

        /* Call this from the main activity to shutdown the connection */
        public void cancel() {
            try {
                mmSocket.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "ConnectedThread(): Exception in cancel()");
            }
        }
    }


// Connecting as a client
// http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth.html#ConnectingAsAClient
private class ConnectThread extends Thread {
    private /*final*/ BluetoothSocket mmSocket;
    private /*final*/ BluetoothDevice mmDevice;

    public ConnectThread(BluetoothDevice device) {
        // Use a temporary object that is later assigned to mmSocket,
        // because mmSocket is final
        BluetoothSocket tmp = null;
        mmDevice = device;

        // Get a BluetoothSocket to connect with the given BluetoothDevice
        try {
            // MY_UUID is the app's UUID string, also used by the server code TODO
            tmp = device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(mUUID);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "ConnectThread() : Unable to create temp socket.");
        }
        mmSocket = tmp;
        Log.i(TAG, "Socket obtained (Connect): " + mmSocket.toString());
    }

    public void run() {
        // Cancel discovery because it will slow down the connection
        mBluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();

        try {
            // Connect the device through the socket. This will block
            // until it succeeds or throws an exception
            mmSocket.connect();
        } catch (IOException connectException) {
            // Unable to connect; close the socket and get out
            Log.e(TAG, "ConnectThread().run() : Unable to connect.");
            try {
                mmSocket.close();
            } catch (IOException closeException) {
                Log.e(TAG, "ConnectThread().run() : Unable to close socket.");
            }
            return;
        }

        // Do work to manage the connection (in a separate thread) TODO
        Log.i(TAG, "ConnectThread().run() : Ready to manage connection.");
        mConnectedSocket = mmSocket;
        manageConnectedSocket(mConnectedSocket);
    }

    private void manageConnectedSocket(BluetoothSocket mmSocket) {
        mConnectedThread = new ConnectedThread(mmSocket);
        mConnectedThread.start();
    }

    /** Will cancel an in-progress connection, and close the socket */
    public void cancel() {
        try {
            mmSocket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) { }

        mmSocket = null;
        Log.i(TAG, "ConnectThread().cancel() successful");
    }
}
```

I'm connecting and reading/writing data from/to a Bluetooth module using code based on [Android's example for managing a bluetooth connection](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth.html#ManagingAConnection/). I can only read the data properly if I log the number of bytes read first:

```
    Log.i(TAG, "Read (" + bytes + ") bytes.");
```

Without that line, the next log will not show anything.

```
    Log.i(TAG, "Bytes from stream (" + bytes + "): " + readBytesStr);
```

Replacing the first log with an assignment did not help.

```
    int numReadBytes = bytes;
```

Based on the answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8409180/reading-data-from-bluetooth-device-in-android/) question, I also tried to use DataInputStream's readFully(), but it never read the expected input in full (despite having a large enough buffer).

Is there any reason why the log makes this work properly?

Comment: Can you post the full code of how the connectedThread is getting called ? It can possibly(bare chances) be a synchronization issue between threads .Also can you show your logcat ouput ?

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I actually updated my code to include ConnectThread, the class calling ConnectedThread in its run() method. I investigated the logs more carefully and found that the lines I'm missing actually show up when the log is dumped without any filters. I'm filtering to only see entries logged in my Bluetooth class. I'm not sure what the problem is, but it's not related to the original question anymore. This is in Android Studio 1.4.1.